# JSF 1.2 not working at all inside JSP pages

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsf, spring-boot

I'm working on an old project trying to get it back to working state with Jetty, Spring & Spring Boot, and it uses JSF 1.2 on which i'm not really familiar with. It also has ibm taglib libraries that I was suppose to get rid of, but I thought the problem was part of me missing the libraries so for the time being I added them to the project.

I'm having and major issue where as I fill the user credentials (login & password) to the page, the controller receives them as null values for some reason. It feels like actually all the #{} inside my login page are not registered to the JSF.

The exact error is

> javax.faces.FacesException: #
>   {aaController.login}: java.lang.NullPointerException

For the dependency part I have jsf-api, jsf-impl, jsf-ibm, odc-jsf for the jsf-libaries.

**My web.xml looks like this**:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.JSP_UPDATE_CHECK</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.LOAD_FACES_CONFIG_AT_STARTUP</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
</context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.DISABLE_JWL_MULTIPART_CONTEXT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.RESOURCE_EXPIRE_MS</param-name>
        <param-value>31536000000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.DATETIME_ASSIST_STRICTNESS</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.NUMBER_ASSIST_STRICTNESS</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.USE_UNENCODED_CONTEXT_PATH</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.JS_RESOURCE_SERVLET_CACHE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.ENCODING_MAPPING</param-name>
        <param-value>converter.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.USE_HXCLIENT_FULL</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ibm.faces.MAX_REQUEST_CONTENT_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
    <param-value>100</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
    <param-value>100</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.displayConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <display-name>AaFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>AaFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>orgmanager.AaFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>loginpage</param-name>
        <param-value>/orgmanagerWeb/faces/Login.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logoutpage</param-name>
        <param-value>/orgmanagerWeb/faces/Logout.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AaFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/Jsp/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/html_extended.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

**Important parts of faces-config.xml looks like this:**

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
          version="1.2">

<application>
    <message-bundle>Messages</message-bundle>
    <state-manager>com.ibm.faces.application.DevelopmentStateManager</state-manager>
    <property-resolver>com.ibm.faces.databind.SelectItemsPropResolver</property-resolver>
    <variable-resolver>com.ibm.faces.databind.SelectItemsVarResolver</variable-resolver>
</application>
<factory>
    <faces-context-factory>com.ibm.faces.context.AjaxFacesContextFactory</faces-context-factory>
    <render-kit-factory>com.ibm.faces.renderkit.AjaxRenderKitFactory</render-kit-factory>
</factory>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>aaController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>orgmanager.aaController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>role</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
        <value>INTERNAL</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>

    <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/Login.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>ok</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Jsp/ManagerFrontpage.jsp</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{aaController.logout}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>ok</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Logout.jsp</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

**My Login.jsp looks like this** with tags

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended" prefix="hx"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<META name="GENERATOR" content="IBM Software Development Platform">
<META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<LINK href="theme/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<TITLE>Organisation Manager</TITLE>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="theme/standardiwsadpan.css"
      type="text/css">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme/stylesheet.css"
      title="Style">

</HEAD>
<f:view>
<BODY>

<h:form styleClass="form" id="loginform">

    <TABLE border="0" class="SisaankirjausTaulukko">
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" align="center" class="Mustalihavoitu">Organisation manager</TD>

        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" height="5"><IMG border="0" src="kuvat/tyhja.gif"></TD>

        </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD class="Mustalihavoitu">Login</TD>
            <TD><h:inputText styleClass="inputText" tabindex="1" id="kayttajatunnus" size="8"
                             value="#{aaController.loginView.login}"></h:inputText></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD class="Mustalihavoitu">Password</TD>
            <TD><h:inputSecret styleClass="inputText" tabindex="2" id="password" size="8"
                               value="#{aaController.loginView.password}"></h:inputSecret></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" height="5"><IMG border="0" src="kuvat/tyhja.gif"></TD>

        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" align="right"><hx:commandExButton type="submit"
                                                           value="Sign in" styleClass="submit-button90"
                                                           id="button1" action="#{aaController.login}"
                                                           tabindex="3"></hx:commandExButton></TD>
        </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
</h:form>
</BODY>
```

**My Controller looks like this:**

```
public class AaController extends BaseController {
public static final int ROLE_INTERNAL = 1;
public static final int ROLE_EXTERNAL = 2;

private loginView loginView = new loginView();
private int role;

public String login() throws OrgHallintaException {
    String result = null;
    AaFasadi aaFasadi = new AaFasadi();
    log.info("Loggin in");


    if (aaFasadi.login(loginView.getLogin(), loginView.getPassword())) {

        if (aaFasadi.getEnviroment().trim().equals("PRODUCTION")) {
            loginView.setEnviroment("        ");
        } else {
            loginView.setEnviroment(aaFasadi.getEnviroment());
        }
        result = "ok";

    } else {
        result = "error";
    }

    return result;
}

public String logout() {
    AaFasadi aaFasadi = new AaFasadi();
    aaFasadi.logout();
    return "ok";
}

public loginView getloginView() {
    return loginView;
}

public Kayttaja getUser() {
    return AaFasadi.getUser();
}
```

}

**And the Class that Controller calls looks like this**

```
public class AaFasadi {

private String enviroment="";

private static final String USER_SESSION_KEY = "orgmanager.User";

public static User getUser() {
    ServletRequest req = (ServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();                     
    return getUser(req);
}

public static User getUser(ServletRequest req) {        
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

    User user = (User) request.getSession(true).getAttribute(USER_SESSION_KEY);

    return user;

}

public boolean login(String LoginName, String password) throws OrgHallintaException {

    User user = null;

    try {           
            PersonelLoginTask personelLoginTask = new PersonelLoginTask();
            PersonelLoginView personelLoginView = toimihenkiloSisaankirjausTehtava.execute(LoginName.toUpperCase(), password);

        if (personelLoginView != null) {
            if (personelLoginView.getEnviroment().trim().equals("PRODUCTION"))
                personelLoginView.setEnviroment("        ");
            User = new DefaultUserImpl(personelLoginView);
            Enviroment = personelLoginView.getEnviroment();
            }

    } catch (TehtavanHallintaException e) {
        System.out.println("User " + Usertunnus + " Login failed " + e);
    }


    if (User != null) {

        ServletRequest req = (ServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();                     
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;        
        request.getSession(true).setAttribute(User_SESSION_KEY, User);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void logout() {
    ServletRequest req = (ServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();                     
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;        
    request.getSession(true).removeAttribute(User_SESSION_KEY);
    request.getSession().invalidate();               
}



public String getEnviroment() {
    return enviroment;
}

public void setEnviroment(String ymparisto) {
    this.enviroment = enviroment;
}
```

}

For some reason my Login.jsp pages aaController.loginView.login & aaController.loginView.password don't work at all and they are returning null values and i don't know why. the loginView has proper Get and Set methods in it's class. Is there something wrong with my JSF configuration?

**My loginview looks like this**

```
public class loginView extends BaseView {

private String login;
private String password;
private String Enviroment;
private Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());




public String getlogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setlogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getpassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setpassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEnviroment() {
    return Enviroment;
}

public void setEnviroment(String Enviroment) {
    this.Enviroment = Enviroment;
}


public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the scope of your bean ? How looks like the class `loginView` ? Could you use two separate fields in the bean to login instead of using loginView class ?

Comment: Hi Omar. I added the loginView there to be shown. The scope of the aaController is Session. Should I change it?

Comment: I'm also having this issue that when i enter the Login.jsp page the on the login input field the value "#{aaController.loginView.login}" is displayed on the field. Should this happen normally?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer was quite silly, but I finally found it out. I was using the web.xml schema version 2.4, but It needed 2.5 to work.